# Better way to count total page views?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter

I am developing an eCommerce website which contains around 2000-3000 products(no.can be increase in near future).So i need to count total page views for a particular product.

i know it can be simply done by just updating a mysql table on each page load but it's not the right way to do this because some one just press the reload button again again and the page views goes up.

So i want to do it in a better way so total views no. somewhat closer to the unique/real one.

i just came up with an idea that i can do it in 3 ways:\

**1.Using cookies** so if i just store cookie for each product then check against it for next unique visit then it can be done but i think it's not the better way to do this because if no of total cookies grows up then it will effect my page performance on each page request.

**2.Using session** i can use session to store data about each product and the visitor identity so i can track that is it a unique visit or a repeating one.But i think session data size also increase if a user visit more & more products with same session.
So is it good to use session for this purpose?

**3.Use databse** i can make a table `page_views` then update the count data by checking a time delay between the last visit and by matching the IP address and session id.

so please suggest me that which method is better to use and the best way to implement that method.

I am using **PHP(Codeigniter 2.0.1)+Mysql**

Comment: I would go for cookies to get the most accurate results

Comment: guess you can only realy on IP + time delay and store infos on DB. For my eCommerce sites I use this method. Mixing with cookies control can be good, just don't use persistent cookies ^^. But what if end user has disabled cookies ? or comes with a mobile without cookies management ? If the proj is big, you can check Google's Analytics.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a neat way to do this with for example Google Analytics?

Comment: @danneth: you've anticipated my edit, I was thinking about the same right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a new table to store session ID variable, along with an expire time of let's say 2 hours. You can create a cookie with this ID on the client server, so that you don't have to use MySQL queries repeatedly.

In my intranet, I have only created a `last_visitor_ip` column in my web-hits table, and I am storing the last IP there, so that continuous refreshes are not counted. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. 3 is not a good idea, because often many different users can appear to have the same IP address (eg, if they are coming from a large organization).  I think no. 1/2 is the best approach (I treat them as the same solution since you would normally implement a session by creating a cookie).  But why would you create a cookie for each page?  Just track distinct product/page views per cookie/session.

Comment: thanks for the point on IP address,i am also thinking about that but i just forgot to mention it,anyways thanks.But i am creating cookie for each product so that i can identify that same user is not visiting the same product again.If i am doing something wrong then please suggest me

Comment: You only need one cookie for each user.  Just add a "session id" column to your page views table.  That way you'll be able to avoid double-counting the same product for the same user.